# python3 3d array class as list

Tags: python-3.x, multidimensional-array

I'm taking a class through OReilly Technical School, and the assignment is to adapt a `2-d array class` with a list `implementation` into a `3-d array class`.

Here's my adaptation:

```
import array as sys_array
```

class array:

```
def __init__(self, M, N, O):
    "Create 3-D array of lists stuffed with zeroes"
    self._data = sys_array.array("i", [0] * M * N * O)
    self._rows = M
    self._cols = N
    self._depth = O

def __getitem__(self, key):
    "returns the appropriate element for a three-element tuple subscript tuple."
    row, col, depth = self._validate_key(key)
    return self._data[row*self._cols+col*self._depth+depth]

def __setitem__(self, key, value):
    "sets the appropriate element for a three-element subscript tuple."
    row, col, depth = self._validate_key(key)
    self._data[row*self._cols+col*self._depth+depth] = value

def _validate_key(self, key):
    """Validates a key against the array's shape, returning good tuples.
    Raises KeyError on problems."""
    row, col, depth = key
    if (0 <= row < self._rows and 0 <= col < self._cols and 0 <= depth < self._depth):
        return key
    raise KeyError("subscript out of range")
```

When I test it with the following code, I have a problem, and I suspect the `getitem` and `setitem` statements, in particular the 
`self._data[row*self._cols+col*self._depth+depth]` indexing phrase, but I am not seeing the problem here if there is one.  Here's the test code and the problem:

```
if name == "main":
    for N in range(6):
        a = array(N,N,N)
        for i in range(N):
            a[i,i,i] = 1
        for i in range(N):
            for j in range(N):
                for k in range(N):
                    if i==j==k and a[i,j,k] == 1:
                        print(" \nYay! *a[{},{},{}] = 1 * ".format(i,j,k))
                    if a[i,j,k] == 1 and not i==j==k:
                        print(" \n+++ Crap!!! a[{},{},{}] = 1  +++ ".format(i,j,k))
```

I should not get any "Craps!" but I do.  Could anyone help me see what I'm missing?

Thanks!
Dave

Comment: it should be `if __name__ == "__main__":`. but that does not solve your problem.

Comment: Yes, it was, but apparently I didn't insert the <code> tags correctly or format the statement properly the first time.  Oops.

Answer (score 0):

you need to account for the _depth when caltulating the array index.

```
def __getitem__(self, key):
    "returns the appropriate element for a three-element tuple subscript tuple."
    row, col, depth = self._validate_key(key)
    return self._data[row*self._cols*self._depth + col*self._depth + depth]

def __setitem__(self, key, value):
    "sets the appropriate element for a three-element subscript tuple."
    print(key)
    row, col, depth = self._validate_key(key)
    self._data[row*self._cols*self._depth + col*self._depth + depth] = value
```

just in case: a print statement for debugging:

```
def __str__(self):
    '''
    '''
    ret = ''
    for row in range(self._rows):
        for col in range(self._cols):
            for depth in range(self._depth):
                print(row, col, depth)
                ret += '{} '.format(self[row, col, depth])
            ret += '\n'
        ret += '\n'
    return  ret
```

Comment: Ah!  I needed to add another " * self._depth "  Thanks!  I really appreciate the help!